# Must type something to comment? Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, submit, chat

I'm working on a chat app with Meteor and I want to make it so you have to type something in order for your message to send (so you can just hit enter a bunch of times to have your name show up in the chat). Unfortunately I have no idea how to do this so I hope somebody here can help. Here is the code that runs the chat app:

Javascript:

```
// render all of our messages in the ui
Template.chatBox.helpers({
  "messages": function() {
    return chatCollection.find();
  }
});

// get the value for handlerbar helper user
Template.chatMessage.helpers({
  "user": function() {
    if(this.userId == 'me') {
      return this.userId;
    } else if(this.userId) {
      getUsername(this.userId);
      return Session.get('user-' + this.userId);
    } else {
      return 'anonymous-' + this.subscriptionId;
    }
  }
});

// when Send Chat clicked at the message to the collection
Template.chatBox.events({
    "click #send": function() {
        if (Meteor.user() == null) {
            alert("You must login to post");
            return;
        }
            $('#messages').animate({"scrollTop": $('#messages')[0].scrollHeight}, "fast");
            var message = $('#chat-message').val();
            chatCollection.insert({
                userId: 'me',
                message: message
            });
            $('#chat-message').val('');

            //Validation
            var bot =Check_bots();

            if(bot==false)
            {    
            //add the message to the stream
            chatStream.emit('chat', message);
       }
        else
        {

        }
    },

    "keypress #chat-message": function(e) {
        if (Meteor.user() == null) {
            alert("You must login to post");
            return;
        }
        if (e.which == 13) {

          //Validation
       var bot =Check_bots();

        if(bot==false)
        {
            $('#messages').animate({"scrollTop": $('#messages')[0].scrollHeight}, "fast");
            console.log("you pressed enter");
            e.preventDefault();
            //repeat function from #send click event here
            var message = $('#chat-message').val();
            chatCollection.insert({
                userId: 'me',
                message: message
            });
            $('#chat-message').val('');

            //add the message to the stream
            chatStream.emit('chat', message);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
  }
});

chatStream.on('chat', function(message) {
  chatCollection.insert({
    userId: this.userId,
    subscriptionId: this.subscriptionId,
    message: message
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a `Meteor` specific question but rather just a simple `JavaScript` one. All you would need to do is check the `length` of the message:

```
$('#messages').animate({"scrollTop": $('#messages')[0].scrollHeight}, "fast");
var message = $('#chat-message').val();

// check to see if the message has any characters in it
if (!message.length) {
    alert("You must enter a valid message!");
    return;
}

chatCollection.insert({
    userId: 'me',
    message: message
});
$('#chat-message').val('');
```

You could also check for a certain number of characters by replacing `!message.length` with something like `message.length > 3`.